# jQuery keyup event does not fetch correct values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML form which is dynamically generated. The form contains an input field and an hidden input field. So, number of times it's dynamically generated depends on the user. IDs and names of the input field are also set dynamically. I am relying on classes to fetch values from the input fields when user types something into the input box.

Here's a static code of my html form

```
<div id="choose_subjects_div2" class="form-group" >
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control onesubject" id="subj_1" name="subj_1" value="8">
      <input type="number" class="form-control onetotal" id="tot_1" name="tot_1">
   </div>
   <p></p>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control onesubject" id="subj_2" name="subj_1" value="5">
      <input type="number" class="form-control onetotal" id="tot_2" name="tot_1" ">
   </div>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

I want the value of the input field and the hidden field associated with it to do some db operations.

This is the jQuery that I am using.

```
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
  clearTimeout (timer);
  timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
 };
})();

$('.onetotal').keyup(function() {
  delay(function(){
      var xxx=$('.onetotal').val();
      var hiddenx = $('.onetotal').siblings('.onesubject').attr('value');
    alert(xxx +'and' +hiddenx );
  }, 1000 );
});
```

The keyup event works after a delay of 1 second.

The values are fetched wrongly. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/b2d9859t/).

Comment: You have same `ids`. Change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get values from the same inputs keyup was triggered on, so you need to use `$(this)` instead of `$('.onetotal')` inside `delay` function:

```
$('.onetotal').keyup(function () {
    delay(function () {
        var xxx = $(this).val();
        var hiddenx = $(this).siblings('.onesubject').val();
        alert(xxx + ' and ' + hiddenx);
    }.bind(this), 1000);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/b2d9859t/1/

Comment: hidden field values are fetch correctly but input field values are not fetched at all. @dfsq

Comment: both hidden and text field values are fetched correctly in demo, did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you select all of the hidden inputs, and `val()` returns you the value of the first one. You should use `this` or `event.target` to get the current input and it's neighbor.

```
$('.onetotal').keyup(function(event) {
   var $current = $(this)
   delay(function(){
       var xxx=$current.val(),
           hiddenx = $current.siblings('.onesubject').attr('value');
       alert(xxx +'and' +hiddenx );
 }, 1000 );
```

});

Comment: hidden field values are fetch correctly but input field values are not fetched at all @culebrón